# Entity framework query optimization for homepage model mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, query-performance

I built an news web application by using MVC 5 & Entity Framework 6. The owner has already entered 1000+ articles in 1 month. The application's homepage needs a lot of objects from database like,

Authors, Posts, Comments, Videos etc. So i created partials in my homepageview and in my homepage action i'm binding a model which holds all the data to be supplied to the partials.

I used glimpse to test the EF 6 performance and I've also ran tests on google page insights the server response time is increasing by the increasing amount of articles on website. It is actually around 1200ms which is slow and also the glimpse is saying that Connection Open time in SQL is 1200ms when loading main page.

So what i need is some tips about the code i've on the mainpages action here is my action codes any performance increasing tips are much appreciated;

```
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Cache1Hour")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Home()
    {
        var pageModel = new HomePageModel();

        //Eager Load Database Objects
        var allPosts = await db.Posts.Include("Authors").Include("Media").Include("PostCategories").ToListAsync();
        var allCategories = await db.PostCategories.Include("Posts").ToListAsync();
        var allMedia = await db.Media.ToListAsync();
        var allAuthors = await db.Authors.Include("Posts").Include("Media").ToListAsync();
        var allEstates = await db.Estates.Include("Media").ToListAsync();
        var allAdverts = await db.Adverts.Include("Media").ToListAsync();

        //Categories
        pageModel.PublishedCategories = allCategories.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && !x.IsOnHeader && !x.IsPrivate).ToList();
        //Videos
        pageModel.Videos = allMedia.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.IsVideo).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).ToList();
        //CornerPosts
        pageModel.CornerPosts = allPosts.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.IsPublished && x.PostType == 1).OrderByDescending(x => x.PostDate).Take(20).ToList();
        //Vitrin Module
        pageModel.VitrinCategories = allCategories.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.IsOnHeader).ToList();
        //Authors
        pageModel.Authors = allAuthors.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.Posts.Count > 0).OrderByDescending(x => x.AuthorName).ToList();
        //Slider News
        pageModel.SliderNews = allPosts.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.IsPublished && x.PostType == 2 && x.IsOnSlider).OrderByDescending(x => x.PostId).Take(20).ToList();
        //Adverts
        pageModel.Adverts = allAdverts.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.AdvertArea == 1).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Take(20).ToList();
        //Private Category
        pageModel.PrivateCategory = allCategories.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.IsPrivate).FirstOrDefault();
        //Latest Posts
        pageModel.LatestPosts = allPosts.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.IsPublished && x.PostType == 2).OrderByDescending(x => x.PostDate).Take(20).ToList();
        //Estates
        pageModel.Estates = allEstates.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.IsPublished).OrderBy(x => x.AdDate).Take(10).ToList();

        return View(pageModel);
    }
```

Since the modal needs different where queries on posts dbset i'm getting all posts and then querying the List instead of directly querying the database again and again. But i can also change that if thats a problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should begin with removing the first `ToListAsync` calls: they fetch all records and later on you filter and `Take`.

Comment: You are loading `allPosts` and then only `Take`ing 20 of them for the view?

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the number of returned records on the DB side. It will be much faster to query twice the DB for 20 records than fetching 1000 records and filtering in memory. When you fetch a lot of rows from DB, creation of EF objects is very expensive. Also filtering can be faster on DB side - it can use index if exists.